# Наследование переменных у классов

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

python3. Интересует наследование у классов, а конкретно: можно ли наследовать от родительских классов переменные? Например, есть 3 класса и всем им нужны одни и те же значения, например, высота и ширина экрана. Можно ли получать эти значения одним из классов, а потом другими классами наследовать эти значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял Ваш вопрос:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, w=200, h=100):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

# Наследуются аргументы по умолчанию
class B(A):
    ...

b = B()

print(b.w, b.h) # 200, 100
```

---

Если же речь о том, что аргументов по умолчанию нет, а они получаются в конструкторе в результате некоторых действий (у меня просто написано `=100`, но алгоритм может быть сложнее, например, вызов функций для получения ширины экрана), то можно сделать так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = 100
        self.h = 200

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # или в данном случае A.__init__(self)
        self.d = 300

b = B()

print(b.w, b.h, b.d) # 200, 100, 300
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ли использовать переменные класса A в классе B? То есть не выходить из класса для их ввода/вывода, как показано в конце, а взять значения из переменных родительского класса А в классе В и использовать их в классе В без необходимости приписывания к конструктору `def __init__(self, ...)` дополнительных переменных? То есть, я имею в виду, просто дать значения переменным только родительскому классу `class A: def __init__(self, a); self.a = 100` и унаследовать классом B значения этих переменных, то есть просто написать в конструкторе класса, например, `self.b = A.a`.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, да, потому что конструктор в `B` от `A` должен унаследоваться, соответственно, после того, как в классе `A` в конструкторе установлено `self.a = ...`, то в классе `B` эта переменная должна тажке быть и равняться тому же значению, соответственно, её можно использовать (ну только либо `A().a`, либо `variable_of_type_A.a`)

Comment: Единственное, тут надо аккуратно эти переменные именовать, поскольку в `python` это механизм "приватных" переменных (например `__a` -- это якобы "приватная" переменная). Строго говоря, это не настоящие приватные переменные, но в контексте Вашего примера они могут создать проблемы

Comment: Но вот только как это сделать? Я про "передачу" переменных/значений в другой класс

Comment: @criemp Ну если класс -- наследник того, откуда нужно передать значения -- можно просто написать, например, `self.d = self.w + 300` (вместо того, где у меня в классе `B` написано `self.d = 300`). Если не наследник -- то A().w + 300

Comment: Именно это и нужно было мне, спасибо большое <3

Answer (score 2):

Конечно можно

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     some_field = 1
   ...:

In [2]: class B(A):
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [3]: b = B()

In [4]: b.some_field
Out[4]: 1
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я, наверное, не правильно задал вопрос, я бы хотел узнать как можно наследовать переменные в классе, без выхода из него. Я имею в виду, унаследовать переменную у класса, для работы с ней в другом классе без кода вне класса.

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: Есть 3 класса. Всем им нужны одинаковые входные данные, например, ширина, высота экрана и какая-то константа. Все эти данные одинаковые для этих трех классов и приходится каждому классу давать эти данные. И вопрос: можно ли дать эти данные одному классу, а другими унаследовать эти данные в другом классе?

Comment: Похоже, речь о том, чтоб `__init__` наследовался: в классе `A` определяете метод `__init__(self, a): self.a = a` (к примеру), теперь можно писать `v = A(1)`, и если будете наследоваться от класса `A`: `class B(A)`, то и `__init__` тоже унаследуется и можно писать `v = B(1)`

Comment: Блин, это не совсем то. Например, есть `class A: def __init__(self, a); self.a = a` и есть другой класс `class B(A)` и мне нужно, чтобы класс унаследовал значение переменной `self.a`, то есть, чтобы было по типу: `self.b` (переменная в классе B) `=` `self.a` (переменная из класса A), либо, я мог просто использовать эту переменную `self.a`, будто это переменная есть и в B классе.